# How can I display image from SQL table to xtrareport picturebox C#?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I created a QrCode on my invoice form, then I save this Qrcode as an image in a SQL table.

I want to display the image of the Qrcode from SQL table in a Xtrareport.

Any idea how to do that?

[image]

Comment: How is it stored to the database? Show us your code

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the QR image as Binary as Type in SQL.
2. In XtraReport, access the DB via SqlDataSource and generate a Query to obtain stored binary data.
3. Set the QR code image column name for Query in the Expression property of the XRPictureBox that you placed in XtraReport.
4. When a report is generated, the image is automatically displayed in the XRPictureBox that you placed in the report.

This is how my project shows the company logo placed in the report.